# How to increase width of stroke of an Ai File in PSD

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I draw an illustration from a source Image. Exported that as PSD file did coloring there. Suddenly my Client asked me to make the stroke width bigger. He was okay with initial stroke width. I am dumbfounded. Is there anyway to do that in photoshop? Without starting from scratch?

Thank you. Please help. I am in deep trouble.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You didn't keep the AI file with all that work in it?

Comment: I exported as PSD. In that PSD file, (when I opened that in Photoshop) I had the AI file as a flat layer, I could not edit that. Some line I had to draw as 'Shape'. Did you ask this? I have AI file saved.

Comment: You may simply be able to go back and change the stroke weight in Illustrator.. then select all, copy, and paste back into Photoshop.

Comment: So easy! You are right. I didn't know I can copy paste ai into psd. i just tried that as "Pixel". Thank you Scott.

Comment: I told my client I am having tooth pain. Need to think of an escape. I just could not figure it out. Thank gawwd It's  a new client. And he is very generous. Old one would ask "Do u have any tooth left"?

Comment: "Photohop file" is in accordance with front tooth loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new layer to your PSD. Paste or place to it better width curves. Adjust the layer transparency.

If curves are not needed equally everywhere insert a full white layer mask. Paint more or less black to the mask where new curves are not needed or they must be less visible.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the AI file with strokes...

You may simply be able to go back and change the stroke weight in Illustrator.. then select all, copy, and paste back into Photoshop.

Comment: 